How to request a URL every 30 seconds on a server?
I have a Google Cloud Function that I would like to trigger every 30 seconds. The function's trigger is set to a URL, so I must request the URL to run it. My goal is to run the function every 30 seconds.
I have set up a cronjob on Google Cloud Scheduler, and the cronjob requests the URL every minute. This is the shortest interval cronjobs can have. How can I request the URL of my function more often?
I have thought of setting up another cronjob that runs 30 seconds after every minute. It would be a solution, but I don't know how to implement it. I cannot specify when a cronjob runs for the first time (in seconds, like at 7:00:30 AM). Another idea that I have is to put a sleep statement after the cronjob command * * * * *, but it was not allowed on Google or other cronjob websites.
Any other thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Edit: I will not keep a device on to run some code to keep calling the URL, as that defeats the purpose of creating a Cloud Function in the first place. I want the URL to be requested automatically on a server I do not have to manage, so regular crontabs on Ubuntu (such as the ones including sleep) do not work, as those cron expressions are not allowed on Google Cloud Scheduler or other online cron services.


Put a sleep in the second cronjob's code.

Can I run a cron job more frequently than every minute?

This question is similar to: Running a cron every 30 seconds. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@tripleee, U880D, and ceejayoz, thank you for your suggestions. However, my question has nothing to do with Linux as the cronjob has to be on Google Cloud Scheduler or
a similar service such as cron-job.org. I've edited my question and added clarifications.

The cloud is just somebody else's computer.

If the scheduler doesn't allow you to run arbitrary commands then no, you can't.

you can't set less than a minute so the workaround would be to set a sleep in your code. So, the code runs once and then sleep 30 and run again (a loop)

Thanks, @Puteri, but that won't work as it would result in my Google Cloud Function running for more than 30 seconds every minute. The cost would be too high.
